# How to stop a Flowable from emitting more items

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room

I've got a question about `Flowables`. I already have a few solutions for this issue, but I would like to double-check if these are the best possible solutions or not.

**Context**

I have an Interactor that is supposed to bookmark recipes on the DB. It looks like this:

```
    /**
     * This Interactor marks a recipe as "bookmarked" on the DB. The Interactor actually switches
     * the isBookmarked value of the related recipeId. If it was marked as true, it switches its value
     * to false. If it was false, then it switches its value to true.
     */
    class BookmarkRecipeInteractorImpl(
        private val recipesCacheRepository: RecipesCacheRepository
    ) : BookmarkRecipeInteractor {
        override fun execute(recipeId: Int, callback: BookmarkRecipeInteractor.Callback) {
            // Fetches the recipe from DB. The getRecipeById(recipeId) function returns a Flowable.
            // Internally, within the RecipesCacheRepository, I'm using room.
            recipesCacheRepository.getRecipeById(recipeId).flatMap { originalRecipe ->
                // Switches the isBookmarked value
                val updatedRecipe = originalRecipe.copy(
                    isBookmarked = !originalRecipe.isBookmarked
                )
                // Update the DB
                recipesCacheRepository.updateRecipe(updatedRecipe)
                // Here's the issue, since I'm updating a DB record and the getRecipeById returns
                // a Flowable, as soon as I update the DB, the getRecipeById is going to get triggered
                // again, and switch the value again, and again, and again...
            }
            .subscribe(
                {
                    callback.onSuccessfullyBookmarkedRecipe(it.response)
                },
                {
                    callback.onErrorFetchingRecipes()
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

So, if you follow the code, the error is pretty straightforward. I get stuck on a loop, where I constantly change the recipe record.

**Possible solutions**

**1)** Have two different functions on my DAO, one called `getRecipeByIdFlowable(id)` that returns a Flowable, and another called `getRecipeByIdSingle(id)` that returns a rx.Single. That way I can expose the `getRecipeByIdSingle(id)` through the Repository and use it instead of the function that returns the Flowable. That way I cut the loop.

Pro: It works.

Con: I don't like having functions like this on my DAO.

**2)** Save the `Disposable` on a `lateinit` property and dispose it as soon as the subscriber triggers the `onNext()`.

Pro: It works.

Con: I don't like having to do something like this, feels hacky.

**3)** Using `...getRecipeById(recipeId).take(1).flatMap...` so it only handles the first emitted object.

Pro: It works, it looks tidy.

Con: I'm not sure if there's a better way to do it.

**Question**

Ideally, I would like to call some function that *just allows me to disable* the `Flowable` behavior and prevent it from emitting more items if the DB changes. So far the solution that I like the most is #3, but I'm not really sure if this is the right way to do it.

Thanks!

**Edit 1**

I'm just adding a bit more of information about the use case here. I need an Interactor that given a **recipeId** changes the **isBookmarked** value on DB to its oposite.

The DB records look like:

```
    data class DbRecipeDto(
        @PrimaryKey
        val id: Int,
        val name: String,
        val ingredients: List<String>,
        val isBookmarked: Boolean = false
    )
```

I know that maybe there's some other ways in which I could tackle this issue differently. Maybe I could pass the recipeId arg and a bookmark (Boolean) argument and just run the update query.

But *this use case it is totally made up, just an example*; The thing that I'm trying to figure out **how to prevent a Flowable from emitting more items if something changes on the DB**.

Comment: Not sure what your use case is but I'm just wondering: why do you need to update your db while you're retrieving it from room at the same time? Couldn't you have a separate observable for updating db instead?

Comment: @ChristilynArjona Thanks, I edited my question to provide some more info about the use case. I'm not sure if I understand what you say, but I need to **fetch** the `DbRecipeDTO` record to know its `isBookmarked` value and then **update** the DB. Please let me know if there's something else that you need to know, or that I'm not explaining here.

Comment: Option 3: `take(1)`.

Comment: Been a few months since I did RX, but pretty sure if you want your flowable to stop doing work (and by proxy, stop emitting items) you should dispose of it... Sure, you can take(1) from the stream, meaning that you'll create a flowable which emits just the first value from the upstream flowable, but then you may as well have modelled the whole stream with a single no?

Comment: @ThomasCook Yeah, the thing that I didn't explain here (because I didn't want this to get too confusing) is that I'm using the `getRecipesById()` somewhere else, where I actually need it to behave as a Flowable and emit items every time a row changes. That being said, I didn't want to create two functions in my DAO (option #1) I wanted to reuse this function and make it behave as a Single.

Comment: In that case, my answer below should meet your requirements.

Comment: Also, the devil is always in the details ;-)

Comment: @ThomasCook Totally, it is the cleanest solution so far. I'll probably keep this question open until EOD, and approve your answer if no one as a better solution :)

Comment: Yea no sweat, there may well be a better way of achieving what you want. Also, the final paragraph of my answer may be incorrect (I'm fairly sure it's correct, but not certain)

Comment: Here, I've asked a question to clarify my last paragraph (answers to this may be of interest to you): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59752373/does-take1-stop-the-upstream-flowable-doing-work

Answer (score 1):

You should probably call `.take(1).singleOrError()` on the end of `getRecipeById(recipeId)`.

This will take the first item (or the error) emitted by the `Flowable` retrieved by calling `getRecipeById` and wrap it in a `Single`. In my opinion this correctly matches the semantics of what you want to achieve.

In addition, if I recall correctly, because you will be subscribing on a `Single` by doing this, your `Flowable` will not continue to do work after the first item is consumed by the downstream call to `singleOrError`.