# Does take(1) stop the upstream flowable doing work?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

Let's assume we have some Flowable that looks like:

```
val exampleFlowable = Flowable.create<Int>({ emitter ->
    while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1))
        emitter.onNext(1)
    }
}, BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

And then I call `take(1)` on it and `subscribe` to it like so (notice, disposing of the disposable in the `subscribe` block):

```
var disposable: Disposable? = null

disposable = exampleFlowable.take(1)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({ first ->
            disposable?.dispose()
        })
```

Will the `exampleFlowable` stop doing work when the value is consumed in the `subscribe` block?

How about if I didn't dispose in the subscribe block? Would `exampleFlowable` still continue to do work then?

Also, what if I called `singleOrError` after calling `take(1)` and didn't dispose in the `subscribe` block? Would the `exampleFlowable` continue to do work in this case, or does converting the stream to a `Single` mean the upstream will only do work until a single value OR error is emitted? For instance:

```
   exampleFlowable.take(1).singleOrError()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ single ->

            })
```

Comment: Your `exampleFlowable` only emits one item and then stops doing anything on its own. `singleOrError` would hang because it requires an `onComplete` to succeed or another `onNext` to fail after the your only `onNext`. If you are using `create`, you are responsible for checking the downstream has issued a cancel by evaluating `emitter.isCancelled()`. Also the [Flowable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html) javadoc gives an example for working with `create`.

Comment: Oh crikey, yea let me update the question - I rushed it as on lunch break.

Comment: Ah, so even with my edit, the `singleOrError` is going to block waiting for an `onComplete` or `onError` to be called. Man I need to brush up, I've gone rusty :-/

Comment: `take(1)` cancels after one item and signals `onComplete` so that specific chain won't hang.

Comment: Ah ok, that's pretty nifty. And presumably that extrapolates to `take(n)` invoking `onComplete` after `n` items?

Comment: And of course, `take(1)` signalling `onComplete` after first item will cause `singleOrError` to consume the item, which in turn will invoke the subscriber. And, because `onComplete` has been signalled and propagated down the stream, the entire stream is now essentially disposed and won't continue to do work?

Comment: Yes as it is indicated in the [javadocs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#take-long-).

Comment: I don't have access to the RX source code right now, only the http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#take-long-

Which implies but doesn't explicitly state that onComplete will be invoked when n items have been emitted. Sorry for the slight laziness on my part there.

Comment: Oh, I guess that's what the terminal line on the marble doc indicates.

Comment: Yes, as indicated by the legend at the top: https://raw.github.com/wiki/ReactiveX/RxJava/images/rx-operators/legend.png

Comment: Makes sense, also I obviously didn't read: "This method returns a Publisher that will invoke a subscribing Subscriber's onNext function a maximum of count times before invoking onComplete."

Height of laziness, sorry for time waste :-)